# How to Save a row of column in a data table

Tags: visualforce

I have a data table and when I click save (only 1 button for the page). I only need those rows with inputted `time__c` field to be saved. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you mean that when user enter data in other columns then those records should not be updated? It should only update records when use enter input in  time__c field?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
List<youObj__c> objToUpdate = new List<yourObj__c>();
for(yourObj__c yo : pageObjList) //suppose the list you put on VF page in the datatable is called pageObjList
{
    if(yo.time__c != null)
    {
        objToUpdate.add(yo);
    }
}
update objToUpdate;
```